# how to make DisplayName in MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, petapoco

while I was building MVC5 model with SQLite. the time span is tricky so I stored the tick instead. but then I get trouble on display name for it.

```
[PetaPoco.TableName("UserStatus")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("iUserId", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class User
{
    [Column]
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public int iUserId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string sUserName { get; set; }

    //[DisplayName("Average Time")] this line won't work
    public TimeSpan tsAvgTime;

    [Column]
    public long longAvgTimeTick
    {
        get { return tsAvgTime.Ticks; }
        set { tsAvgTalkTime = new TimeSpan(value); }
    }
}
```

so what should I do to add a display name instead of change the display on the view.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is because you have not created **Property** but a **Field**.

It should be a property to make it work.

Change it to :

```
[DisplayName("Average Time")] 
public TimeSpan tsAvgTime {get;set;}
```

Now this should work.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed you are using a backing field. You need to apply the attribute on the property  which is `longAvgTimeTick` here and make the field private i.e. `private TimeSpan tsAvgTime`

so it should be :

```
private TimeSpan tsAvgTime;

[Column]
[DisplayName("Average Time")]
public long longAvgTimeTick
{
    get { return tsAvgTime.Ticks; }
    set { tsAvgTalkTime = new TimeSpan(value); }
}
```

Comment: the longAvgTime is for store in the SQLite, but I don't want to show the long value (it would be ugly and unreadable, eg:60000000000). the shown value is only TimeSpan tsAvgTime so it will be easy to get(eg:01:40:00). but when i display it shows the name tsAvgTime so I want a DisplayName "Average Time" on the html form.